# Valence Electrons of Molecules

Tags: inorganic-chemistry

Why do we say that hydrogen has 1 valence electron? Hydrogen (H2) is a molecule so how does this make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Don't misunderstand it. When you say `Hydrogen has 1 valence electron`, it means you are referring to Hydrogen atom (H) by default. Although, it's ambiguous saying `Hydrogen has 1 valence electron`. It should be said as `Hydrogen atom has 1 valence electron`.

Comment: Come to think of it, there is no ambiguity. Molecules don't have valence electrons; atoms do.